# I was Doing a practice problem In java to find the maximum value in an array but i don't get the solution can anybody explain it to me?

Tags: java, arrays

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahpnk.png)
This is the solution I looked up but except for the array and for each loop i don't get any of that
I am a total beginner by the way.

I tried to understand the problem but didn't quite get it properly, I would really like some explanation.

```java
int[] a7={8,90,-75,863,-7845};
int min3=0;
for (int element1:a7){
  if (element1<min3){
   min3=element1;
  }
}
System.out.printIn("The Minimum Value of this array is"+min3);
```

Comment: Why did you look up a solution instead of working out how to solve the problem?

Comment: Step through the coded in a debugger line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are so many ways to get the maximum element in array.

Easy One + More Efficient

1. assume first element is max,
2. loop through array from 1 to n
3. check if current element is greater than previous max or not
   if yes, so store it in max variable, if not keep old max value

[See this the link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-find-largest-element-in-an-array/)

at the end, variable `max` will hold maximum element in the array

Keep in mind: Problem Solving is for your mindset, to make your brain active, and don't copy paste, or see solution after short time, take your time maybe 25min or more depending on your personality

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.